# Frontend and backend hybrid oauth2 flow?

Tags: python, django, rest, oauth-2.0, dropbox

My app needs to retrieve user's dropbox data in both frontend when user is present(js) and backend when user is away(python/django)

I understand after authorization I will receive a token code. Does that mean I should use this token code for both JS and Python when communicating with Dropbox? or should I use my python backend as a proxy when communicating with Dropbox?

I am worried by using a proxy it will add unnecessary delay to the user experience.

Comment: You're worried about user experience. I think the proxy is the quickest path with the least redirects to/from dropbox. Assume they are on a mobile device with slow network and your server is on a fast network then you'll want the fast network doing all the auth flows as much as possible.

Comment: What you _should_ do is subjective and will depend on what's important to you and your app, but for reference, it is possible to use the same access token in both JavaScript and Python clients for the Dropbox API.